# Store int, float and boolean in same database column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Is there a sane way of storing int, float and boolean values in the same column in Postgres?
If have something like that:

| rid | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2d9c5bdc-dfc5-4ce5-888f-59d06b5065d0 | 2021-01-01 00:00:10.000000 +00:00 | true |
| 039264ad-af42-43a0-806b-294c878827fe | 2020-01-03 10:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2 |
| b3b1f808-d3c3-4b6a-8fe6-c9f5af61d517 | 2021-01-01 00:00:10.000000 +00:00 | 43.2 |

Currently I'm using jsonb to store it, the problem however now is, that I can't filter in the table with for instance the greater operator.

The query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM points 
WHERE value > 0;
```

gives back the error:

> `ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb > integer: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

For me it's okay to handle boolean as 1 or 0 in case of `true` or `false`. Is there any possibility to achieve that with jsonb or is there maybe another super type which lets me use a column that is able to use all three types?

Performance is not so much of a concern here, as I'm going to have very few records inside of that table, max 5k I guess.

Comment: If you want to use `>`, how is that supposed to work with `true`? Is this really one field or two or even three?

Comment: Without seeing examples of `value` there is not really much that can be done in way of an answer.  Also there is no explanation as to why you want to mix types in a column? To me that is a sign of poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out, regardless of the jsonb fields value, that you can compare it to other jsonb in postgres. That means, I can for instance do the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM points
WHERE val > '5'
```

This correctly gives me back only the third row. It just ignores the `bool` value. To filter for a certain bool I can achieve that with the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM points
WHERE val = 'true'
```

This is good enough for me. I even could hold timestamps in the json column and compare them using this methodology.
Another way of solving the problem after all your comments seem to be to make the column a numeric. This would work as well, but requires more client side conversion, as I would have to have a second type column, remembering what the actual type is. This type should than be used on the client side to convert the value back into its og value. For integers its trivial, for booleans like @schwern suggested, one can use `1` and `0`, for dates, one could use the unix timestamp representation.

When I now want to search for a certain value, the `type` has to be contained in the `where` clause as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you were just storing integers and floats, normally you'd use a `float` or [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) column.

But there's that pesky `true`.

You could cast the JSON...

```
select *
from test
where value::float > 1;
```

...but there's that pesky `true`.

You have to convert the boolean to a number to make it work.

```
select *
from test
where
  (case when value = 'true' then 1.0 when value = 'false' then 0.0 else value::float end) >= 1;
```

Or ignore it.

This having to work around the type system suggests that `value` is actually two or even three different fields crammed into one. Consider separating them into multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should skip the rows where `value` is not `number` and cast the value to `numeric`, e.g.:

```sql
with points(id, value) as (
values
    (1, 'true'::jsonb),
    (2, '2'),
    (3, '43.2')
)

select *
from points
where jsonb_typeof(value) = 'number'
and value::text::numeric > 0;

 id | value
----+-------
  2 | 2
  3 | 43.2
(2 rows)
```